# multiple datalist on same page

Tags: php, html, datalist

I have this code:

```
<label for="name">Name:</label> <?php include("datalist_name.php"); ?>
<label for="state">State:</label> <?php include("datalist_state.php"); ?>
<label for="gender">Gender:</label> <?php include("datalist_gender.php"); ?>
```

It works just the first one. If I delete the first, than the second is working.
I try run each one separate, and they all work. the problem is when they are together.
I get the value from sql.

Comment: All we can do here is _guess_ : most likely the included files terminate the process, maybe an `exit()` call.

Comment: Great, you managed to specifically not show the actually important part here … But I’m gonna hazard a guess anyway, you’re likely duplicating HTML IDs somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem. i closed the connection in each php file. i leave open the connection and now it works. thanks